# Job Sequencing Problem with three parameters

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, greedy

I have Job Sequencing Problem with three parameters where every task has time to be completed(in weeks) and a deadline that mush be finished before it.

In other words, any week, Job can be worked on at most. All jobs have a hard deadline, which means they must be completed before the deadline. The task is to arrange the jobs so that a high profit shall be accumulated.

**Example**

Input:

```
JobID   Time    Profit    Deadline
  1      8        100        13
  2      1        100        1
  3      1        100        3  
  4      1        100        2
  5      4        100        6
```

Output

**Total profit:** 400

**Jobs in order:** 2 4 3 1

I have been trying to apply greedy algorithm but it only works with two parameters(**profit** & **deadline**) but here I have to take **time** into consideration

Answer (score 0):

The solution can be obtained through dynamic programming. Before diving into the recursion, something to develop the intuition:

*(I'm assuming any task will start no earlier than the earliest date in the deadline. That is, for your example, it would be day 1.)*

Let `D_i` denote the time in days it takes to complete Task (or job) `T_i`. Denote the profits for task `T_i` as `P_i`s.

On a calendar day `C` (the hypothetical calendar starting on earliest day of the deadline), you can be doing only one task per the problem definition. It could be one of `T_1`, `T_2`, `T_3`, `T_4` or `T_5`.

If you were doing task `T_1` on day `C`, it means that you started the task on `C - D_1` day of the calendar. Similarly, if you were doing task `T_2` on day `C`, then you started on the task on day `C - D_2`, and so on.

You could be doing any one of the tasks `T_1`, `T_2`, `T_3`, `T_4` or `T_5` on day `C`. Therefore, the profit you get by doing the last task in the sequence on day `C` is one of `P_1`, `P_2`, `P_3`, `P_4` or `P_5`. If you add the profit of Task `T_i` that you were doing on the last day (i.e. `P_i`) to the maximum profit until day `C - D_i`, not including that task, for each `1<= i <= 5`, you'll get the set of maximum profits you could possibly make on day `C`. The highest among these profits is what you're looking for. In the end, the answer would be the solution for day **13**. (`C = 13`)

(*I've tweaked your example a slight bit for more generality*)

[image]

I'll leave it up to you to figure out how to codify this into a programming construct. On a broad level, you'll need two variables for your dynamic programming recursion:

1. Set of tasks (i.e., modeling `T_i`)
2. Calendar Days (i.e., modeling `C`)

Comment: There is value to both a greedy approach and this one.  In particular the number of sets of tasks is exponential in the number of tasks.  As that number grows, eventually you have a performance and memory problem.

Comment: Agreed. If the number of tasks is < 32, then we can represent each set of selected tasks as an integer in most programming languages. We can surely optimize, based on the "bank for the buck" approach you listed in your answer, but we can't escape the exponential factor for long, even with that. (Unless I am missing something.)

Answer (score 0):

Prioritize the jobs by profit per unit of time, breaking ties for the one that finishes first.

In other words think of it as dollars per hour and work on the job that pays you fastest.

```
JobID   Time    Profit    Deadline   Priority
  1      8        100        13        12.5
  2      1        100        1        100
  3      1        100        3        100
  4      1        100        2        100
  5      4        100        6         25
```

And now we look at jobs 2, 4, 3, 5, then 1 in that order.  We can do the first three and the last.

Comment: The priority alone, as profit per unit time is not necessarily guaranteed to give the correct result. There's an aspect of feasibility within the deadline too. You can have priority for a job that can't be completed in 1 day as 100 dollar/hour and other that can be completed in 1 day as 50 dollar/hour. If the deadline was 1 day, then you need to discard the first job to calculate the max profit. So, for the final solution, you do need some mechanism to consider all possibilities of tasks that can be done within the deadline.

Answer (score 0):

```py
#Brute Force
def jobScheduling(jobs):
    ans=0
    jobs.sort(key=lambda x:x[2],reverse=True)
    m=max(jobs, key=lambda x:x[1])[1]
    ans=[0]*(m+1)
    count=0
    for i,k,p in jobs:
        for j in range(k,0,-1):
            if ans[j]<p:
                ans[j]=p
                count+=1
                break
    return count,sum(ans)
#Time complexity:N*LOG(N)+O(N^2)
#Space complexity:O(MAX(JOBS[1])
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#Optimal Approach
def jobScheduling(jobs):
    ans=0
    jobs.sort(key=lambda x:x[1])
    heap=[]
    for i,j,pro in jobs:
        ans+=pro
        heapq.heappush(heap,pro)
        while len(heap)>j:
            ans-=heapq.heappop(heap)
    return len(heap),ans
#Time complexity:N*LOG(N)
#Space complexity:O(MAX(JOBS[1])
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).